# Regular Expression - removing a line(English) and attaching it to the end of upper line(Korean)

Tags: c++, regex, text

I have this text like below:

```
아니다
bukan

싫다
tidak suka

훌륭하다
bagus
```

And I am trying to remove the English line(English Alphabets) and attach it to the end of upper line(Korean Alphabets) like this:

```
아니다bukan

싫다tidak suka

훌륭하다bagus
```

Now, Finally find almost close regular expression, which is this:

```
[가-힣]\R
```

However, It makes the text file like this:

```
아니bukan

싫tidak suka

훌륭하bagus
```

The problem is removing the one word of Korean too.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ `std::regex` does not support Unicode property classes like `\p{Hangul}`, but you may use the equivalent character class, `[\u1100-\u11FF\u302E\u302F\u3131-\u318E\u3200-\u321E\u3260-\u327E\uA960-\uA97C\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uFFA0-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC]`, see [this reference](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7BHangul%7D&abb=on&esc=on&g=&i=).

Besides, `\R` is not supported either. You may probably just use `\r?\n` to match Windows/Linux style line endings, or `(?:\r\n?|\n)` to also support MacOS line endings.

Next, if you match and consume a Korean char, when replacing, you need to capture it into a capturing group and use a backreference to the group in the replacement pattern.

So, you may use

```
([\u1100-\u11FF\u302E\u302F\u3131-\u318E\u3200-\u321E\u3260-\u327E\uA960-\uA97C\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uFFA0-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC])(?:\r\n?|\n)
```

Replace with `$1` to put back the Korean char into the resulting string.

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/R50gx8/1).

Answer (score 1):

The regex for the set of all Korean characters in unicode is this:

```
\p{Hangul}
```

There is more information here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Maybe you also need a + after your group of characters?

Use the [\p{Hangul}]+\R regular expression instead of what you're using now.

Comment: @ChanjungKim How come it does not? Are you using Swift or Objective-C?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew C++

Comment: @ChanjungKim Then why tag your question with Swift/Obj-C `nsregularexpression` class? I fixed the tags.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Oh, maybe it was my mistake. Thanks!